# Why I get null in the first click and in the second or any click after it i get input element correct, react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, frontend

This is the App.js which i passed input element as a props to children component to display the element when button clicked in the children component, but it log null first time and after that it log element correctly, i want to know if the browser excute document.querySelector() before html render or what?

```js
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>React App</h1>

            <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, 'Moaz', 22)}>Click</button>

            <input className="inp"></input>

            <Person age={this.state.persons[0].age} name={this.state.persons[0].name} inp={document.querySelector('.inp')}></Person>

            <Person age={this.state.persons[1].age} name={this.state.persons[1].name} inp={document.querySelector('.inp')}></Person>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the component.js which should display input element

```js
const Person = props => {
    const outHandler = () => {
        console.log(props.inp);
    };

    return (
        <div onClick={outHandler}>
            I'm a {props.name} and i'm {props.age} years old, he like {propsState.hoppies} and speak {propsState.languages} <button onClick={switchHoppiesHandler}>Change</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

At the point at which the HTML markup is being constructed by the render method on initial mount, no HTML markup corresponding to the component exists in the document at that time.

While you could use a ref:

```
this.inputRef = React.createRef();
```

```
<input className="inp" ref={this.inputRef}></input>
```

pass it down as a prop, and then do

```
console.log(props.inputRef.current)
```

If you're trying to get the *value* in the input, you should add a change handler to the input, put the input value into state, and pass it down as a prop instead:

```
const outHandler = () => {
  console.log(props.inputValue);
};
```

```
<input
  className="inp"
  onChange={e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })}
></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i want to know why this behaviour occur, why i get null in the first time

Comment: See the first sentence of the answer. *At the point at which the HTML markup is being constructed by the render method on initial mount, no HTML markup corresponding to the component exists in the document at that time.* so the `querySelector` doesn't see it in the document and returns `null`.